# Vim: Replacing the End of the Line

Tags: vim

In Vim, how is it possible to replace the remaining of a line with the yanked text? If I press "D", the yanked text will be replaced with the deleted text.

Also, how is it possible to yank to the end of the line? If I press "Y", it will yank the whole line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Press `v` to enter **visual mode** on the starting character of the selection. Then hit `$` to go to the end of the line. After that, hit `y` to yank the selection.

So:

`v$y`

Instead of yanking, use `p` to paste. This will paste over the selection. So after you use `D` to delete some text, do:

`v$p`

This will paste the deleted text over the selection.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I thought you meant press v$y to yank. Yeah, that works, thanks.

Answer (score 13):

Two ways you can replace text to the end of the line with previously yanked text:

1. `v$p` — `v` to enter visual mode; `$` to move to end of line; `p` to paste over highlighted text.
2. `D"0p` — the last yanked (as opposed to deleted) text is stored in register 0, so: `D` to delete to end of line; `"0` to select register 0; `p` to paste that register.

Comment: Yeah, I also didn't know about the register comment.
Is there anyway to select two answers as the accepted answer? :)

Answer (score 4):

Your questions seems to be thoroughly answered by others at this point (`v$p` and `y$`), but I wanted to one additional piece of information:

To yank to end of line, the default way is `y$`. However, it is a fairly common practice to `map Y y$` in your `.vimrc`, since the default behavior of `Y` is redundant with `yy`, and is inconsistent with other mappings, like `D` and `C`.

Comment: Thanks for this comment, it is very useful. I will add that to my .vimrc :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to delete text without affecting the main (unnamed) register, delete your text into the "black hole register", called `"_`.  Do this via `"_D`.  Then the unnamed register will be unaffected and you can paste your previously-yanked text as normal.

See `:h quote_`.

Answer (score 1):

```
y$ - yank to end of line
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I'd do it:

1. `"ay$` (yank from cursor to end of line into register `a`)
2. Move cursor to desired replace position.
3. `D` (delete to the end of the line)
4. `"ap` (paste the text yanked in step 1)

Admittedly, this is very similar to [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3585760/vim-replacing-the-end-of-the-line/3585849#3585849) but I prefer explicitly specifying a register because it forces me to think about what I'm doing.  I could see myself accidentally overwriting register `0` if I got distracted or tried to do something else.